# Go struct initialization

Tags: go

How come Go can be initialized using both `&Person` and `Person`?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (p Person) Who() string {
    return "Person: " + p.name
}

func main() {
    var p1 = &Person{"Adam"}
    fmt.Println(p1.Who()) // Adam
    var p2 = Person{"Ben"}
    fmt.Println(p2.Who()) // Ben
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question? What do you see as the issue in your sample code?

Comment: `Person{}` creates a Person and `&` takes the address of that Person variable. It's not the same. Please take the Tour of Go to learn the syntax and how to work with pointers.

Answer (score 5):

`p2 := Person{"Ben"}` initializes a `Person` struct by assigning `"Ben"` to `name`, and assigned that to `p2`. `p2` is of a value type `Person`.

`p1 := &Person{"Adam"}` initializes a `Person` struct by assigning `"Adam"` to `name`, and then assigns the address of that struct to `p1`. `p1` is of a pointer type `*Person`.

`Who()` is a method defined for a receiver of value type `Person`, which means, the functionality always receives a copy of the receiving instance. This is an important factor when it comes to mutability. This also works with pointer handles, such as in your example with `p2`, but the receiver will continue to be a local copy of the instance, unless you change the receiver definition to `(p *Person)`, which will provide a local copy of the pointer reference.